# Matlab: command for counting occurrences in ascending order not cumulatively?

Tags: matlab, sum

This must be asked before but I cannot find it now. It calculates the amount of zeros, add the count of zeros to vector, then calculate the amount of ones, append the count of ones to the vector and so on. If zero count, make it as zero.

> **Is there some zero command to do this counting in Matlab?**

**Input ---> Output**

```
0 1 1 1 2 3 3 4 7 ---> [1,3,1,2,1,0,0,1]

0 1 1 1 ---> 1 3

2 7 ----> 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Does order matter? Would `7 0 1 1 1 2 3 4 3` give the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the total count of occurrences of each number, use [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/histc.html):

```
x = [0 1 1 1 2 3 3 4 7]; %// example data
histc(x, 0:max(x))
```